# Where is the language level setting in android studio 1.2?

Tags: android, lambda

when i want to use java8 lambda in android studio 1.2(my java sdk was `java8`),the android studio say

> "...not support language level"

So, I go to the setting find language level,but couldn't  find it . Any one use the as 1.2 can found the language level setting ?thanks for the answers.

Comment: android doesn't support java 1.8

Comment: If and when Android does support Java 1.8, syntax should be driven by Gradle: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

Comment: Thanks everyone.i had solve it.i user "alt + enter" ,when the prompt show in the error."alt + enter" help me change the language level

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in File -> ProjectStructure  ... there you can define the Level for each module