# How can i search in a custom object type array list ? whats is best and fastest way

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

i have custom object type of array list and i want search a string is exists in objects value ,then how can i find it out that object those
 have search string

Comment: Please create a MCVE to show us what you tried http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Find string in array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304214/java-find-string-in-array-list)

Comment: those answers is not my solution i want fastest way to use HashSet for search in array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private String val;

    public Test(String s) {
        this.val = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new Test("one"));
        values.add(new Test("two"));
        values.add(new Test("three"));

        System.out.println(listContains(values, "two"));
        System.out.println(listContains(values, "five"));
    }

    public static boolean listContains(List<Test> customTypeList, String searchedString) {
        return customTypeList.stream().anyMatch((v) -> v.val.contains(searchedString));
    }
}
```

If you're searching for fastest solution and searched strings are exactly the values from objects in your list (not interested in substrings), then you may want to map strings from your objects to these object's references like this:

```
        (...)
        List<Test> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new Test("one"));
        values.add(new Test("two"));
        values.add(new Test("three"));

        Map<String, Test> indices = new HashMap<>();
        for (Test v : values) {
            indices.put(v.val, v);
        }

        System.out.println(indices.containsKey("two"));
        System.out.println(indices.containsKey("five"));
        // or...
        System.out.println(indices.keySet().contains("two"));
        System.out.println(indices.keySet().contains("five"));
        (...)
```

IMPORTANT: You would need to update your indices whenever you change the content of your list though. Note that in this case string values inside objects must be valid keys for these objects (unique values). Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> values = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Test> indices = new HashMap<>();

        addToList(values, indices, new Test("one"));
        addToList(values, indices, new Test("two"));
        addToList(values, indices, new Test("three"));

        System.out.println(indices.keySet().contains("two"));
        System.out.println(indices.keySet().contains("five"));

        removeFromList(values, indices, "two");

        System.out.println(indices.keySet().contains("two"));
    }

    private static void addToList(List<Test> values, Map<String, Test> indices, Test item) {
        values.add(item);
        indices.put(item.val, item);
    }

    private static void removeFromList(List<Test> values, Map<String, Test> indices, String key) {
        Test item = indices.remove(key);
        values.remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: there is no method named as stream()  array list

Comment: In Java 8 there is:
java.util.Collection =>
public java.util.stream.Stream<E> stream() [ See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html ]

Comment: i have Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14) that doesn't give any method stream on arraylist

Comment: I have tested it on Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14). What IDE are you using? Maybe you dont have a proper language level enabled there... See - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915259/how-to-change-project-language-level-for-all-project-in-intellij

Comment: i was using Android Studio Ide

Comment: Unfortunatelly Android seems not to support Java 1.8 yet, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954170/where-is-the-language-level-setting-in-android-studio-1-2 (however this info is from July 2015 and thus needs to be confirmed).

Comment: not working in Android Studio this stream() method not show

Comment: So you can simply use foreach in the checking method

`public static boolean listContains(List<Test> customTypeList, String searchedString) {
        for (Test e : customTypeList) { if (e.val.contains(searchedString)) return true; }
        return false;
    }`
Or the solution from my answer (with additional HashMap) if you need HashSet speed (and checking exact values).